# Manually enable undodir, when needed

Tags: vim

I have enabled `undodir`, to keep track of changes I make even after I close my vim session.

I sometimes want to edit a file, make some changes, save it, then return to the original file of that session. (This might be one of the possible use cases)

If I had `undodir` disabled, I could simply keep hitting `u` until it showed me a message.

So I want `undodir` to be disabled in undo/redo by default, and I should have a command to enable it when needed.

All changes to the file must be tracked in either states, at all times.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean `undofile` option?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the documentation, only setting [`undodir`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27undodir%27) does nothing unless [`undofile`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27udf%27) is set to `true`.

So, I assume that you want to activate `undofile` for certain files.

First thing that comes in mind is a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27modeline%27) in order to set `undofile` to `true` for certain files. But unfortunately, this doesn't work.

The issue, however, is present on the vim developer mailing list and there was a fix provided in January: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim.devel/32896. This fix could be present in current sources; so if you'd like to try, grab the latest vim sources, build it and check if you could use a modeline for setting [`udf`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27udf%27)

Until there's an official version containing that fix, you could get around your issue using [`undofile.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3198). Excerpt of it's description:

> If you want 'undofile' only for certain files, you will notice that **'undofile' cannot be set in a modeline**, or once the buffer is loaded (because an existing undo file will not be loaded then).  Bram suggests to use a BufReadPre autocmd which sets 'undofile' before the buffer is loaded.  This script does the steps for you.